# Could Not Find Resource in Google Material Dependency When Using FloatingActionButton in Android 4.3.1

Tags: android

Android Version: 4.3.1
Device: Defy Mini

Receiving a crash report on Android 4.3.1 when trying to inflate a layout that contains a `FloatingActionButton`. This component is included in my project by importing the dependency `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`.

The important information from the crash report is the following.

> Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
>
> Resource ID #0x7f080110

I have searched online and the resource matching this is [unlabeled](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/R.id#unlabeled)

Here is how I include the `FloatingActionButton` in my xml layout.

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fab_save"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/fab_controls"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_save"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/whiteColor"
        android:tint="@color/gpsBackground"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Unsure how to proceed. Any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: probably You are using `AndroidX`? Then use `<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton...../>`

Comment: Sorry, I am struggling to see how this is different from the `FloatingActionButton` I am already including?